# How to share a facebook page's post on a facebook group using the facebook c# sdk v 6.x

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I have tried to post a normal post on my Facebook groups using this desktop app that i created and succeeded i can publish normal posts or posts having a link to display its preview normally but when it comes to sharing a some page's post and display a preview some error occurs and the post doesn't get published i don't know why its doing this so i thought i could use some tips around here,,, this is my C# code

> ```
>             var postArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
>             postArgs["message"] = "some status update here";
>             postArgs["link"] = "the desired link;
>             var fb = new FacebookClient(Settings.Default.AccessToken)
>                          {
>                              AppId = CurrentValues.appId,
>                              AppSecret = CurrentValues.appSecret
>                          };
>              await fb.PostTaskAsync(
>                                 string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination)
>                                     ? "/me/feed"
>                                     : string.Format("/{0}/feed", destination),
>                                 postArgs);
> ```

where the method that contains this code is marked as an asynchronous method and "destination" is a method parameter that contains the groupId.